# Can't train brain js with huge data

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, brain.js

I'm trying to make image recognition and localization with brain js

my training data is like this

```
var trainData = [
    {input: [(an array with 29400 float data the value is either 0 , 1 or 0.5)], output: [1]}
];
```

i just train it with only 1 object data

i did train my data and everytime i load the page it won't respond

i also tried to train using array with rougly 300 float data and it works fine

i don't know if the problem is in my code or is it in brain js, because i've seen people train with huge data and they're fine

NOTE: there is no problem in ajax

Here is my code

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){  
    
const net = new brain.NeuralNetwork();


$.get("db.txt",function(res){

    var data = JSON.parse(res);

    var trainingData = res;

    net.train(trainData);

});


});
```

Comment: Did you look for similar “training is slow” problems in the [brain.js github issues page](https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js/issues) ?